# How can I deal with 'Uncaught erorr'? (dart newbie's quastion)

Tags: dart

I ran this code and got the following error.
what should I do to erase **Uncaught Error**?

tesla way of making battery
TESLA WAY OF SET AI
**Uncaught Error: kesla way of making battery!**

```
void main(){


Tesla modelx = Tesla();
  print (modelx.makeBatterry());
  print (modelx.setAI());
  Kesla modelk = Kesla();
  print(modelk.makeBatterry());
}

class Tesla{
  String battery = 'tBattery';
  String aI = 'tAI';
  
  String makeBatterry(){
    return 'tesla way of making battery';
  }
  String setAI(){
    return 'TESLA WAY OF SET AI ';
  }

}

class Kesla implements Tesla{
  @override
  String aI = 'tAI';

  @override
  String battery = 'tBattery';

  @override
  String makeBatterry() {
    throw 'kesla way of making battery!';
  }

  @override
  String setAI() {

    throw 'kesla way of setting  AI!';
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You are throwing an error instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, I assume you meant to return the values in your `Kesla` class rather than throw them.

```dart
class Kesla implements Tesla{
  @override
  String aI = 'tAI';

  @override
  String battery = 'tBattery';

  @override
  String makeBatterry() {
    return 'kesla way of making battery!';
  }

  @override
  String setAI() {
    return 'kesla way of setting  AI!';
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but when i push 'alt+enter', it is automatically made. so I thought when I override, dart use 'throw' instead of 'return'. i will try as 'return'. thank you a lot.

Comment: The autogenerated placeholder code `throw UnimplementedError();` is meant to deliberately cause an exception if you reach that path in your code. It is intended to be replaced entirely. The `throw` keyword is used to cause an exception in dart.